# How to retrieve a PFUser's email that is not the currentUser?

Tags: ios, swift, email, parse-platform, pfuser

In my app I am trying to have users contact each other via email. When a user presses "Contact Seller", I am using a cloud function that sends out an automated email that is handled with Mailgun.

I have access to the current user's email address via:

`let buyerEmail = PFUser.currentUser.objectForKey("email") as! String.`

What is being sold is a PFObject called Product. One of the fields of Product is "seller", which represents the user who posted the product for sale.

I am trying to get the seller's email via this approach:

```
let seller = product.objectForKey("seller") as! PFUser
let sellerEmail = seller.objectForKey("email") as! String
```

However, when I try to run my app, it crashes with the following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "email" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.
```

How can I get the seller's email? Is it something that is not allowed for security reasons? The email field is not hidden in my parse database so I don't see why that would be the reason. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is; The data for the `seller` PFUser hasn't been retrieved.  You need to check `dataAvaiable` on the `seller` and call `fetchIfNeededInackgroundWithBlock` on the `seller` and then access the email in the completion block if it is false - https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:  You could also use `includeKey:seller` in your initial query for items

Answer (score 0):

It should be hidden for security reasons, you should lock the users down. You should just pass the product to the cloud code where you can use the master key and get the user info. Just fetch the user before you try to access the other details.